# Declaring two variables in a for loop

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to declare two variables in the initialization part of a for loop? I want to call a function on each character of a string.

```
for(var i = 0, c = aString.charAt(i); i < aString.length; i++){//problem here: not itterating
    alert("c: "+c)
    func1[typeOfChar(c)]++
}
```

The problem is the string isn't being itterated in the sense `c` is always the first letter of the string.
The `alert` was just for trouble shooting purposes, by the way.

I'm curious, how come `c` doesn't need the `var` keyword when being declared?

UPDATE: got it working. I wasn't going to ask but I notice edits are still being made, I'm used to not using the semi-colons as they are optional. How can a for loop be written without them? I don't add them because I see it as the less the simpler, or do they improve readability?

Comment: sorry for being dense, but couldn't you just put `c = aString.charAt(i)` on the first line of the for loop?

Comment: What have you tried? Does the code you have work? And if not, what error do you see?

Comment: @JasonHall user with >1000 rep, answered 11 questions and has plenty of well ranked questions. I think the community has shown enough faith in this user to assume he tried.

Comment: @Pointy when I add the second `var` I get the error "missing variable name"

Comment: @Celeritas yes of course you're right; I have to check the spec. The `for` loop has its own quirky syntax; it's probably the case that it doesn't need `var` because the first `var` covers the entire comma-separated list (meaning my first comment is wrong :-)

Comment: @Celeritas yes that's what the deal is - when the first part of the `for` stuff is `var` then the whole lot of it is like a `var` statement outside a `for` loop. That means that the `,` isn't really the intra-expression comma operator, but instead the syntactic separator for a variable declaration sequence. Sorry; I probably need more coffee.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You'd like `c` to change at every iteration, not to declare it at the start of the loop, try

```
var i,c;
for(i = 0,c=aString.charAt(0); i < aString.length; ++i, c = aString.charAt(i)){
    alert("c: "+c)
    func1[typeOfChar(c)]++
}
```

For what it's worth I don't think it makes very readable code, I would put it in the first line.

Here is some information [on the comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) you're using.

Also note that javascript has no block scoping for for loops, so you're actually declaring `i` and `c` at the top of the current scope (this is usually the top of the current function, or the top of the global scope).

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maWua/

Comment: @Bergi you are correct, I did not initialize C at the first iteration, loops in javascript are indeed 0 based. I made an edit.

Comment: Btw, the OP did not use the comma operator.

Comment: `"javascript has no block scoping for for loops"` - no longer true for ES6+, the `let` keyword allows you to define block-level scoping. `for (let i=0; i<aString.length; i++)` not only defines `i` just within the loop (without the traditional hoisting mentioned), but creates a closed value for `i` instead of a reference. This avoids the reference errors of passing a reference to `someArray[i]` within the loop and having each call use the final value of `i` instead of the expected value. See other questions about `let` for more info.

Answer (score 41):

Simple way to include multiple incrementing variables in a for loop without nesting. This example declares 3 variables.

```
for (var i = 0, j = 1, n = 2; i < 50, n < 50; i = i + 3, j = j + 3, n = n + 3){
    console.log("variable i: " + i);
    console.log("variable j: " + j);
    console.log("variable n: " + n);
}
```

see codepen [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EZVxGx?editors=1112)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, because `c` is only dependent upon `i` (and an invariant) and it is *not* used the conditional of the loop, I recommend removing it from the loop construct:

```
// (Keep variable hoisting in mind)
for(var i = 0; i < aString.length; i++){
    var c = aString.charAt(i);
    alert("c: "+c);
    // ..
};
```

(The problem with the original is that it *never updated* the value of `c`.)

Answer (score 2):

You should just place `c = aString.charAt(i);` inside the body of the loop.

For example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < aString.length; i++){
    c = aString.charAt(i);
    alert("c: "+c);
    func1[typeOfChar(c)]++ 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
c = aString.charAt(i)
```

`i` is always zero, so it's not going to work as expected. Initialization occurs once and you are trying to get the char during init when i has just been initialized to `0`.

Comment: `i++` should change the value of `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible by using a [multiple `var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), and you did successfully. However, assigning to it only once in the initialisation statement will not make it change.

You will either need to do it once before the loop and after each loop turn

```
for (var i=0, c=str.charAt(i); i<str.length; c=str.charAt(++i)) …
```

or you do it before each turn in the condition

```
for (var i=0, c; c=str.charAt(i), i<str.length; i++) … // comma operator
for (var i=0, c; c=str.charAt(i); i++) … // empty string as condition
```

or just move it inside the loop

```
for (var i=0, c; i<str.length; i++) { c=str.charAt(i); … }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is using `while`,in some case like that it's clearer:

```
var i = 0;
while(i < aString.length){
   c = aString.charAt(i);
   alert("c: "+c)
   func1[typeOfChar(c)]++
   i++;
}
```