# For-in loops with two variable javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Is this possible? [image]

Two variable in for-in loops simulatenous?

```
for (var i in shear_x && var j in moment_x) {

  var overturning_moment = (shear_x[i].results + moment_x[j].results)*moment_arm;

}
```

Comment: No. It isn't. ‏

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: [Should try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14696261/declaring-two-variables-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: You can use a common counter (If such exist, you didn't provide any sample data for us to work with) or try to explain the issue you're having instead of providing a proposed or possible solution using an invalid syntax (Read here about the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem))

Comment: Are you trying to nest two loops?

Answer (score -1):

Your code implies, at least to me, that you really want a single loop counter applied over both objects, at the same time.  I would suggest using a single `for` loop over the common length of the two objects:

```
var length = // length of shear_x
for (var i=0; i < length; ++i) {
    var overturning_moment = (shear_x[i].results + moment_x[i].results) * moment_arm;
    // rest of your loop code
}
```

If I interpreted your requirement incorrectly, then the only option which might come to mind is two nested loops, something like this:

```
for (var i in shear_x) {
    for (var j in moment_x) {
        // your code
    }
}
```